# Counting files in a directory not working

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to count the number of files in a directory and hide a number of buttons corresponding to the total amount of buttons take away the number of files in the directory. At the moment the code appears to not run past the line where it creates the directory, there are no errors but the text doesn't update nor does the button hide.

```vb
Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Class Form2
    Dim username As String
    Dim FriendsArray() As String
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        Form1.Hide()
        username = File.ReadAllText("C:\Program Files\PolarisChatUser\TempUser\UserID.txt")
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Program Files\PolarisChatUser\" + username + "\Friends")
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Program Files\PolarisChatUser\" + username + "\Friends")
            FriendsArray(i) = foundFile
            i = i + 1
        Next
        btnF1.Text = FriendsArray.Length
        If FriendsArray.Length = 0 Then
            btnF1.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

updated code

```html
Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Class Form2
    Dim username As String
    Dim FriendsArray As List(Of String)
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        Form1.Hide()
        username = File.ReadAllText("C:\Program Files\PolarisChatUser\TempUser\UserID.txt")
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Program Files\PolarisChatUser\" + username + "\Friends")
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Program Files\PolarisChatUser\" + username + "\Friends")
            FriendsArray.Add(foundFile)
            i = i + 1
        Next

        btnF1.Text = FriendsArray.Count
        If FriendsArray.Count = 1 Then
            btnF1.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How is that array being initialized?

Comment: Note that you pasted your VB code into a box labeled "HTML". There was no box for VB because snippets are not meant for VB. Use the code formatting tool `{}` instead of the snippet `<>`. See [the help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Be sure your text file does not have a line feed and/or carriage return in it, or call `Trim` after reading the text.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the reading of the username works fine! The issue is with finding the amount of files in the array.

Comment: @LarsTech I am afraid I don't know what that means? care to explain?

Comment: You state in your question, "At the moment the code appears to not run past the line where it creates the directory". Having a carriage return could cause the `CreateDirectory` call to fail to create the folder you think it should.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am sorry I believe there may have been some confusion, the directory creation  works just fine, it's the code after that which doesn't work.

Comment: You don't have any items in your array.  Arrays have to be initialized with their length.  Use a `List<String>` instead.

Comment: @LarsTech what is a list string?

Comment: `Private friends As New List(Of String)`  then add items to it: `friends.Add(foundFile)`

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks I will try that now and see if it works

Comment: @LarsTech How do I find the number of entries in a list string?

Comment: `friends.Count`

Comment: @LarsTech I have now tried this and it has made no difference. thanks for the help though.  it seems to just stop running the code when it gets to the part where it logs the file names. I think that it might just get stuck in a loop.

Comment: Use the debugger.  Put a debug stop on that line and when it reaches it, step through the code line by line.

Comment: @LarsTech I have used the debugger now and I have found that the issue is with the i = i + 1 but I dont know why. it finds the file and I am not sure that it adds it to the list string

Comment: I can't see your new code from here.  Edit your question.

Comment: @LarsTech I have updated it

Comment: You can't add items to your FriendsArray unless you initialize it with "new".  You shouldn't need the "i" variable anymore.

Comment: Standard users haven't had write permissions into the Program Files folder since Windows 2000. You should be putting these items in the Application Data folder instead.

Comment: @LarsTech I have now fixed it with your help. thank you very much.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn its not a problem as all of the users for this program will have Admin

Comment: That's not true. Even when running with administrator privileges, starting with Vista (12 years now) you still need to explicitly authorize administrative access when starting a program. Moreover, it's just poor practice; Application Data is where this stuff belongs.

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetFiles` returns an array of file names in the directory. Simply get the `.Count` or `.Length` property of the array.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TheFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\maryo\Desktop")
    Dim NumberOfFilesInDirectory As Integer = TheFiles.Count
    Debug.Print(NumberOfFilesInDirectory.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
Dim counter As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
MsgBox("Number of files is : " + counter)
```

or Specific File Default

```
FilesInFolder = Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath, "*.Doc").Count

MsgBox("Number of files is : " + FilesInFolder )
```